# How do I order files with like sortOn and filters like select

Tags: haskell

I'm doing a project that aims to create a PDF using the exiftool library and language Haskell and I have some doubts in the creation of functions to order the files. My work originates as PDF now lacks the sorting functions. For example for my dat.hs file contains these files (music, videos)

```
Files {files = [{filename = Video "-4th_dan trailer.mp4" size = "15 MB" ftype = "MP4" copyright = "-" height = "-", width = "720"}
Video {filename = "TheLostInterview.mp4" size = "73 MB" ftype = "MP4" copyright = "-" height = "Bruce_Lee_-_The_Lost_Interview.avi" width = "240"}
Audio {filename = "8bp017-08-nullsleep-humdrumz.mp3" size = "1984 kb", ftype = "MPG / 3" copyright = "-", title = "humdrumz" artist = "nullsleep", year = "2001"}
Audio {filename = "8bp017-04-nullsleep-fluffy_nougat.mp3" size = "1501 kb", ftype = "MPG / 3" copyright = "-", title = "fluffy nougat," artist = "nullsleep" year = "2001"}
```

I now through functions such as `sortOn :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]` and `select ((> 500). size) (dat files)` have to organize these files by size, year, artist ...

Now one problem is the size because I want to sort by size and the size he is set to "15 MB" the MB has to be able to sort out there to
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want `15 MB` to be considered bigger than `1984 kb`.

One way to do this would be to use `sortBy` rather than `sortOn`. `sortBy` takes a comparison function and sorts using that. So you can just write a function that can sort values like `15 mb` properly.

However, this is not the best way to do it. Instead, I suggest you normalize all the sizes to one unit (kb, perhaps). So go through and convert `15 MB` to kilobytes and store it as a number. Then, when you need to print the sizes, have a function that takes a number of kb and prettifies it. This will allow you to easily sort on size.

A way to do this would be to create a `Size` type:

```
newtype Size  = Size Integer deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Then you can make it an instance of `Show` to get the pretty printing working:

```
instance Show Size where
  show (Size s)
    | s < 1000 = show s ++ " kB"
    | s < 1000000 = show (s `div` 1000) ++ " mB"
    | otherwise = show (s `div` 1000000) ++ " gB"
```

To get the size from the input string, you could make it an instance of `Read`.

```
instance Read Size where
  readsPrec _ str = do (size, rest)  <- reads str
                       (unit, rest') <- lex rest
                       let multiplier = fromMaybe 1 $ lookup unit unitSizes
                       return (Size $ multiplier * size, rest')
    where unitSizes = [("mB", 1000), ("gB", 1000000)]
```

You can include variants of unit names (e.g. "mB" and "MB") just by adding more pairs to `unitSizes`. Any unit abbreviation not in the list is just ignored.

Edit: Made the code neater by using Daniel Wagner's suggestion.

Additional notes:

Once you've defined `Size` and made it an instance of all of those type classes, you can use normal sorts on it. You can use `read` on things like `"10 mB"` to get the size. If you use `deriving (show)` on your original data type, it should still work when you replace your strings with `Size`s.

Comment: I'm not sure that my particular Read instance is good code; if anybody could edit and improve it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Thanks in advance for having responded to my question
So I now have to change the type size of the MB pair kb uniform to make a case for all cases right? and these functions do this that thou hast spoken?

Comment: One more thing, the function is quite similar to SortBy sortOn?

is defined in the prelude or do I have to do first?

Thanks again

Comment: @TikhonJelvis How about something like `do { (size, rest) <- reads str; (unit, rest') <- lex rest; multiplier <- fromMaybe [] (lookup unit [("kB", 1), ("mB", 1000), ("gB", 1000000)]); return (multiplier * size) }`?

Comment: I've already put functions indicated in the file dat.hs however is giving an error


No instance for (Show (Integer -> Size))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Integer -> Size))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
    
thanks again

Comment: @user1151066: `sortBy` is in `Data.List` so you'd have to put `import Data.List` in your file if you want to use it. As for your error, it sounds like you tried to do something like `print Size 10`? If so, you have to do `print $ Size 10` or `print (Size 10).

Comment: Now the error its different LI.hs:77:24:
    The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression:
    let multiplier = fromMaybe 1 $ lookup unit unitSizes
Failed, modules loaded: TeX. thanks again
*TeX>

Comment: my data type is this data Files = Files {files:: [File]}
     deriving Show 
data File = Audio{
 filename :: String,
 size :: String,
 ftype :: String,
 copyright :: String,
 title :: String,
 artist :: String,
 year :: String
        } | Video {
 filename :: String,
 size :: String,
 ftype :: String,
 copyright :: String,
 height :: String,
 width :: String
        } deriving Show

Comment: @user1151066: That error was caused because I missed the last line in `instance Read...`. If you update your version, it should be better now. Also, change your data type to have `size :: Size` and update the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: +1 convert `size` from `String` to a meaningful data type...YES! Provide code for nice Show and Read instances YES YES YES! Excellent suggestions.